# How many four-digit numbers can be formed using only the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$ if the digits are not repeated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many four-digit numbers can be formed using only the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$ that are not repeated? How many of these numbers are greater than $3,999$? Justify your
answer.
My approach is $P(6,4)$ since I cannot start with $0$ so the solution is $360$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

For a four-digit number, the first digits must be non-zero and the rest can be any of the given digits.

So, for the first digit, we have $6$ options [anything from $1$ to $6$]. And then, because we can't reuse the digits, $6$, $5$, and $4$ options for the remaining digits.

That means, altogether $6 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 720$ four-digit numbers can be formed under the conditions provided.

For the number to be greater than $3,999$, the first digit must be greater than $3$ i.e. $4$, $5$, or $6$.

Proceeding as we did for the first case, the total number of numbers would be $3 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 360$.

Answer (score 1):

The number must start with $4$, $5$, or $6$. Then there are $6$ choices for the next number, $5$ for the next number, and then $4$. This is a total of $3 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 360$. Indeed, the answer is equivalent to $P(6,4)$, but the reasoning that you are ordering four objects from six is not exactly right. There are seven objects.

Comment: what about the first part of the questioni?

Comment: @KhaledMagdi your posted answer to the first part of the question is wrong.  Assume, for example that the leftmost digit is $~1.~$  Then, you have $~6~$ choices for the next digit, not $~5.$

Comment: My bad. I forgot the first part of the question. Then the answer is $6 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4$, since you have $6$ choices for the first digit.